# 4K video performance with intel 610 UHD graphics

Tags: kubuntu, video, intel, 4k-monitor

This is the VM45 from Asus, contains an Intel Celeron 3865U https://ark.intel.com/products/96507/Intel-Celeron-Processor-3865U-2M-Cache-1_80-GHz which is supposedly the lowest powered processor to provide 4k visuals with the Intel UHD 610. Instructions say, if you want 4k streaming, pair up the RAM, so got an additional module to go in, now 2x 2GB DDR4 2133, 4GB total. 32GB SSD, running Kubuntu 17.10.1 64bit.

Output to a 4k television set, LG 43UJ635V, tried HDMI 1.4 output for 24 fps 4k, also tried through a DisplayPort++ 1.2 adapter to HDMI 2 for 4k at up to 60 FPS.  Through either connection, the miniPC doesn't perform, rendering the video is choppy to varying degrees.

Terrible performance with VLC 2.x and Firefox, improved but still a bit poor with Chrome.  Not sure (could check) which codec used in the videos I've tested with VLC, but I would assume that between YouTube and the browser that the correct codec would be selected for me.

The PC came with a Windows licence, so I'm planning to reinstall Windows tonight just for comparison's sake.  If I have to stick with Windows, I will reluctantly do so.

Essentially, my question is, where's the bottleneck?  Is UHD video playback too much for the hardware?  Should I return the VM45 and build a small form factor PC with a low profile Nvidia 1030, or exchange the VM45 for something with a Core i3 7100U processor for better all-round performance and Intel 620 graphics instead of 610.

OR, is something misconfigured and I just need to apt-get a codec?

EDIT WITH ADDITIONAL INFO
VLC video tested Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Resolution: 3840x2178
Display resolution: 3840x2160
Bitrate ~32300 kbps
Frame rate: 50
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

Video #2
Codec: MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265) (hevc)
Resolution: 3840x1600
Frame rate: 23.976024
Birate ~4800kbps
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

Output of xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4096 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected primary 4096x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   4096x2160     24.00*   23.98
   3840x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080    120.00   100.00   119.88    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1280x1024     60.02
   1360x768      60.02
   1152x864      59.97
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x576i      50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08

A third edit will come shortly with a review of unit's performance under Windows.

---***---

Under Windows, unit performs much better.
The two media files on disk played fine in VLC, that's both the AVC and HEVC.  YouTube video playback in Chrome dropped a frame or two here and there.  EDGE was better, I'd say almost flawless at 24fps, not really capable of 60fps YouTube footage, frames get dropped.

But I'd much rather use Linux.
I'm now testing with today's Daily of Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Saying "4K" isn't very helpful. The  codec used to encode & bitrate will affect your performance. With your setup try h.264 videos & use vaapi. Support for hevc on your iGPU is likely poor to none, probably the later.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to also include the output of `xrandr` command (paste the text, not a screenshot of the terminal, please).

Comment: According to en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/hd_graphics_610 plenty of hardware support for avc, hevc, vp8 and vp9 but is it enough I wonder. I'll add my xrandr output to my question shortly. Will also test performance under MS win 10 this evening GMT. Thanks all!

Comment: By the way, on Win 10, Firefox 58 would not let me select a video resolution above 1440p